# Private classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, oop

I would like a pattern for a nested private class in Objective C.

Requirements are:

- <del>class will not be visible/accessible to other classes.</del>
- class can execute methods (i.e., not a C struct)
- containing class members are visible/accessible to the nested class

Considering the comments, I am simplifying the requirements:

- inner class may be accessible to other classes, but not visible (similar to using a category to hide private methods).
- inner class does not have to be nested

Is it still not possible?

Comment: Sorry, what you're asking for doesn't exist in Obj-C.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: it exists in Obj-C++

Comment: @Dani: Sure, but only if you're talking about C++ classes and not Obj-C classes (as the two are completely different things).

Comment: @KevinBallard: you can say it came from C++, but it doesn't mean it doesn't exist in Obj-C++.

Comment: @Dani: Ovesh specifically asked about classes in Objective-C. It's misleading to talk about classes in C++, because those are *completely separate things*. Just because they use the same name ("class") doesn't mean they're at all related.

Comment: I ammended my question. Still not possible? Care to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Ovesh: Its impossible in Obj-C, but possible in Obj-C++

Comment: Obj-C++ exists to let Obj-C call C++ code. Don't expect it to be good for anything else, like original work.

Comment: @Dani, KevinBallard: Is there no pattern that even comes close? Is it impossible to create a tiny class that's not exposed to the whole world?

Comment: @Oversh: there is, with methods in your `.m` file instead of `.h` file.

Comment: @Oversh: To expand on what Dani said, if you declare and a define a class in one of your `.m` files, it won't be visible outside that file. In general, remember that classes aren't visible in files that don't `#import` their declaration.

Comment: I was curious about this before, check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929300/proper-objective-c-helper-wannabe-private-methods

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Objective-C has no notion of private classes or private instance variables in a formal declarative fashion.

Instead, visibility in Objective-C is entirely controlled by where you declare something.  If it is in a header file, it can be imported by something else.  If it is declared in an implementation file, it cannot (reasonably) be imported and, therefore, is effectively private to that compilation unit.

And by "it", I mean pretty much anything that can be declared;  class, global, etc...

I.e. if you stick an `@interface/@implementation` pair for a class in a `.m` file, that class is effectively private to that compilation unit.  Of course, without namespaces, make sure that class is uniquely named.

---

Consider this:

Foo.h:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
... public interface
@end
```

Foo.m:

```
@interface __FooSupportClass: NSObject
... interface here ...
@end

@implementation __FooSupportClass
@end

@interface Foo()
@property(retain) __FooSupportClass *__fooSupport;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize __fooSupport = fooSupport__;
... etc ...
@end
```

That gives you a private-by-visibility support class only available in your implementation with an instance variable and setter/getter methods on your class that are not visible outside the compilation unit either.

(Note that Objective-C has "instance variables", not "member variables".  They are similar, but you'll be better off using the vocabulary of the language.)

Comment: That was my original approach. However, I need an instance of that inner class to be a member. How can I do that? Would a forward @class declaration do the trick?

Comment: OK, I just checked it. OK, that's the approach I'll go with. Of course, the problem of the containing class members not accessible to the inner class remains.

Comment: How to access a variable of foo from fooSupport? Is it possible?

Comment: @Sakthimuthiah and Ovesh: Give FooSupport a weak (to break retain cycle) pointer to an instance of Foo. Declare Foo's private properties before declaring FooSupport (remember, both are in Foo.m) so that FooSupport will be able to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can have "semi-hidden" private methods.  You can include an interface file that provides extension methods that is in the implementation file and then just implement the methods declared in there.  I was curious about this before and asked a similar question.

[Proper Objective-C Helper "Wannabe" Private methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929300/proper-objective-c-helper-wannabe-private-methods)